# Why the function syntax is not working as arrow syntax in a setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple component that have a template that contains just a Box, the box won't be rendered till showBox is true (it strats as false in data).

```
    <template>
  <div  v-if="showBox" class="Sbox" > 
  </div>
</template>
```

i have this timeout that controls the showing of the box after a (delay) time -delay is a number/prop.
this code uses function syntax with setTimeout and it doesn't work, the box never shows up.

```
mounted(){
     setTimeout(function(){
      this.showBox = true
      console.log("box shows",this.showBox)},this.delay)
      }
```

But after i used the arrow syntax it worked, and that's weird because as i know there is no difference between the two.

```
   mounted(){
  setTimeout(()=> {
  this.showBox = true
  console.log("box shows",this.showBox)},this.delay)
  }
```

the app can be viewed at :[Box component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hn43xd?file=src/components/Box.vue)

Comment: *"as i know there is no difference"* ahh but there is

Answer (score 1):

it's about "losing this". Arrow functions retrieve `this` from the lexical scope, but not in function or function expression. In your case, you can create a "function wrapper", or use `func.bind(obj)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind